# Does Collapse and Scripting functions exist in Foundry Elasticsearch?

Tags: foundry-phonograph

Phono doc says that aggregations are based on Lime syntax, which is a layer on top of elasticsearch 6 (just a subset). Principally FILTER and AGGREGATION. First (filter) is clearly documented in Palantir doc but second is less and I often refer to Elasticsearch 6 (ES6) doc for inspiration.

Now I wonder if some ES6 behaviour are accessible in Phono

Collapse function https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-collapse.html

Scripting and Script Field https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-script-fields.html

Does anyone know if these functions exist in the Phonograph API ?

Comment: Hi GFF_kuma, I have been looking into your question to see if someone would throw an answer. Communicating straight into phonograph is not recommended generally, and you should consider querying via the LTS Objects Gateway which can query OSS/Functions/Actions. If your stack has an exception for this, I would recommend reaching out via internal support mechanisms.

Comment: Thank you. I was trained to use phonograph API and I built logic of my business services based on that API. If I'm reaching phono limits I agree to move to a new logic but I'm not sure of the cost of such migration. Is there similarities between Phono and Object? How differents are they? Is Object the same than Ontology (I heard about that also)? Can I easily setup an Object from my dataset? So much question that I'm affraid to face.